# Is there a pymongo (or another Python library) bulk-save?

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I'm trying to write a function to do a bulk-save to a mongoDB using pymongo, is there a way of doing it? I've already tried using insert and it works for new records but it fails on duplicates. I need the same functionality that you get using save but with a collection of documents (it replaces an already added document with the same _id instead of failing).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you looked at the command line tools and found them wanting? http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/import-export/

Comment: I think the question you are trying to ask is if there is a bulk save in Mongo, not necessarily for pymongo specifically?

Answer (score 1):

you can use bulk insert with option w=0 (ex safe=False), but then you should do a check to see if all documents were actually inserted if this is important for you

Comment: that doesn't do what OP wants at all - it will still fail on the documents that exist.  The real answer is "you can't pass more than one document to save"

Comment: no it will not fail : 
try this:
yourClient.db.collection.insert([{'_id':i}  for i in range (0,100)],w=0)
and then a second time it will not fail

Comment: Of course it will fail - in the sense that the new document will not be saved over the value of the old document. OP wants functionality that replaces an already added document with the same _id not silently fail to replace it!

Comment: Yes, the replacement functionality is the desired one :(